# Javascript pointer to offset in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers

I want to allocate an large array and then return a pointer to an offset into the array. Is that possible in javascript?

```
var biggArray = Float32Array(1000);
var createVec3 = function() {
   return &biggArray[3]; //return pointer to address at offset 3
}
var vec3 = createVec3();
vec3[0] = 10.0;
```

I know javascript does not have pointers but is there anyway to simulate the same behavior?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have pointers.

Comment: You want to access the item at index 3 in biggArray by using vec3[0] and dont want to access the item in the previous index

Comment: To "simulate" the behavior, you can return an `[array, startIndex]` pair and always add `startIndex` to your intended index when accessing the array.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hmm, Yes that could be a good idea

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
var biggArray = Float32Array(1000);
var createVec = function(offset) {
   return {
     set: function(index, value) {
       biggArray[offset + index] = value;
     },
     get: function(index) {
       return biggArray[offset + index];
     }
   };
};

var vec3 = createVec(3);
vec3.set(0, 10.0);
```

Comment: I dont want to allocate memory every time createVec is called, a new object is created every time you do return {...};

Comment: Each time you create a pointer, you also allocate X bytes for the pointer if I'm not mistaken?